# SqlDependency Not firing c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Hi I am trying to implement Sql Dependency into my windows service code. I have already set my service broker as true. I have written this code inside Windows On Start method. The method OnDependencyChange should start as soon as there is new entry in table. But it never happens.
Here is my code,

```
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start("connection 
        string;database=dbName;Integrated Security=True;");
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection 
        string;database=dbName;Integrated Security=True;");
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM 
         UserDetails", connection))
        {


            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);



            dependency.OnChange += new
               OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);


            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Process the DataReader.
            }
        }



     void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
     {
      // Handle the event (for example, invalidate this cache entry).
     }
```

Please help.

Comment: You can't use `SELECT * FROM ...`, use `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM ...` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Maarten. I checked that also. No luck..

Comment: In addition to explicitly specifying the columns you care about, you might also need to specify the schema the table exists in - `SELECT col1, col2 FROM dbo.UserDetails`. If it still doesn't work then ensure Service Broker feature is enabled on the SQL Server instance you are attempting to connect with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got a security problem. If I remember correctly, there is a known issue with permissions required for working with SqlDependency.
First, you need to verify and, eventually, enable the Service Broker feature.
Then, you need to enable [query notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-query-notifications). Only after that, you can enable your SqlDependency events to detect data modifications: [Detecting Changes with SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency)